# Displaying TRichEdit row and column in status bar

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7

We are adding an ASCII editor to our application, and we are using `TRichEdit` in Delphi XE7. We need to display the Row and Column in the status bar, but have not found any code that works with the Key down function. The code below is the current code we are using. The code below works perfect with the mouse down, but the key down is not consistent.

```pascal
Row := SendMessage(asciieditor.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, asciieditor.SelStart, 0);    
Col := asciieditor.SelStart - SendMessage(asciieditor.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, Row, 0);
```

Comment: "*but the key down is not consistent*" - in what way, exactly? Please be more specific. It is possible that the key hasn't actually been processed yet, thus your `SelStart` is not where you are expecting. Try delaying the calculation until after the `OnKeyDown` event has exited. Or use `OnKeyUp` instead. Though, for something like this task, I would probably create a `TAction` and assign an `OnUpdate` event to it to keep the status bar updated. Action `OnUpdate` events are fired whenever the app goes idle after message processing. Or, just use the `TApplication(Events).OnIdle` event.

Comment: Hello Remy. That was it. We moved the call to get the row and column from the richeditkeyup procedure and now it is updating the status bar as expected. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @MRoth: Now see what happens when you enter text using speech recognition! Or dragging a selection from Microsoft Word to your editor (which will not give you an `OnMouseDown` event).

Answer (score 2):

When you want to display the caret position in a Rich Edit control in the status bar, the usual way is to use the editor's `OnSelectionChange` event:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.RichEdit1SelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Format('Row: %d  Col: %d',
    [RichEdit1.CaretPos.Y + 1, RichEdit1.CaretPos.X + 1]);
end;
```

This is fired every time the caret pos or selection end point is moved, which is precisely what you need.

Attempting to keep the status bar updated using mouse and keyboard events is not a good idea. For instance, what if the user is editing or typing without using the mouse or keyboard? (For instance, programmatically or using speech recognition.)

And using `OnIdle` is a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: Just as an FYI, `TRichEdit.CaretPos` is implemented using `EM_EXGETSEL`+`EM_LINEINDEX` for the `X` (row) coordinate, and `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` for the `Y` (column) coordinate. Every time the `CaretPos` is read, the coordinates are re-calculated. So I would suggest caching the result in a local variable.